# Update cache of periodical react-query with refetchInterval from other place

Tags: reactjs, caching, polling, react-query, cache-invalidation

For a counter I am polling the backend periodically with react-query using the `refetchInterval` option:

```js
const { items } = useQuery(
  ["queryKey"],
  requestFn,
  {
    refetchInterval: 5000,
  }
);
...
<Counter>{items.length}</Counter>
```

Alas, when I add or delete an item, it takes up to 5 seconds to be reflected in the counter.

How can I force the counter to update immediatly?

I thought of triggering the query with the same key once after the add/deletion routine, but it doesn't work.

```js
addItem().then(() => useQuery(
  ["queryKey"],
  requestFn,
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd likely want to do `queryClient.invalidateQueries(["queryKey"])` after running the mutation, because that will re-fetch new data right away. This is documented here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/invalidations-from-mutations